# Select2 options in MeteorJS

Tags: javascript, meteor, jquery-select2

I am trying to instantiate a multi-select box with Meteor JS and Select2. My html resides in a template as follows:

```
<template name="selectbox">
     <select id="testbox">
         <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
         <option value="AL">Washington</option>
     </select>
</template>
```

Within my client js I have the following code:

```
Template.selectbox.rendered = function(){
    var options = { allowClear : true, multiple : true }
    $("#testbox").select2(options);
};
```

Unfortunately my browser's console produces the following error:

```
Exception from Deps afterFlush function: Error: Option 'multiple' is not allowed for Select2 when attached to a <select> element.
```

I have also tried placing the following code directly in my client js file (as well as within Template.selectbox.create):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var options = { allowClear : true, multiple : true }
    $("#testbox").select2(options);
});
```

Unfortunately I receive the same error. The peculiar thing is I receive no error if my options are simply:

```
var options = { allowClear : true, placeholder : 'test' }
```

Neither option appears to take affect. However, The rendering of the select box is that of selct2.

Any  idea what could be the issue? Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See how [the example](https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/blob/gh-pages/index.html#L395) on [select2 website](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) is made. According to that code, you should add `multiple` attribute to the select tag, not to js method parameters.

So in your template replace `<select id="testbox">` with `<select multiple id="testbox">`.

Comment: I feel like an idiot but this works! Thanks. Their documentation shows the following which threw me off: `$("#e11_2").select2({
    createSearchChoice:function(term, data) { if ($(data).filter(function() { return this.text.localeCompare(term)===0; }).length===0) {return {id:term, text:term};} },
    multiple: true,
    data: [{id: 0, text: 'story'},{id: 1, text: 'bug'},{id: 2, text: 'task'}]
});`